# Separate twitter status/hyperlink/date with R

Tags: r, twitter

I would to automatically separate the following tweets to get the tweet itself, the hyperlink and the date in three separate columns. Anyone can help? The name of my dataset is DB_YS and it is a txt file.

Here are a few tweets from my data frame:

```
Thank you, everyone!  indyref http://t.co/1kTzqjyGE7 Sep 18, 2014 
  As the polls close, total likes on the @YesScotland Facebook page have passed David Cameron s one.  indyref  voteYes http://t.co/x7IoB1EtfY Sep 18, 2014 
We can be proud of  indyref, which has seen a flourishing of Scotland’s self-confidence as a nation  VoteYes http://t.co/1OqxvbpoS9 Sep 18, 2014 
We can afford world-class public services. A Yes vote means we can strengthen our NHS.  VoteYes  indyref http://t.co/D9Vn5OqStV Sep 18, 2014 
This is a once in a lifetime opportunity to choose a new and better path for Scotland  VoteYes  indyref http://t.co/9knT6Mx4vZ Sep 18, 2014 
Our young people shouldn t have to leave to find decent jobs.  VoteYes  indyref http://t.co/vAE164f0Oy Sep 18, 2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution also using the "stringr" package. It's based on cory's answer but it corrects some errors that would happen if you have unconventional tweets
It assumes that you have a .txt file named DB_YS.txt that contains all your tweets in raw text format. And that you have the library "stringr" installed. Otherwise you have to do install.packages("stringr")

```
library(stringr)
#Load your data into R
RawData <- read.table("DB_YS.txt", sep="\n", header = F)
#Extract the dates into a new vector called dates
dates <- str_extract(RawData$V1, "[A-Za-z]+ \\d+, \\d{4} *$")
#Extract the urls assuming that all urls will start by http and store them in a new vector called url
url <- str_extract(RawData$V1, "http.+")
#Remove the urls from text and store them into a vector called text
text <- gsub("http.+", "", RawData$V1)
#Remove the "indyref" that tells twitter where to put the urls in a tweet and overwrite the result in the text vector
text <- gsub("  indyref", "", text)
#Create a data.frame containing the tidy data
Data <- data.frame(dates, text, url, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I do have some cases where the date doesn't seem to be put in the right column, like for this tweet where everything stays in the «tweet» column: Huge congratulations to everyone in @Team_Scotland for spectacularly beating the medal target already! Still time for more...  GoScotland Jul 29, 2014. Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution from the base package using a series of regular expressions:

```
# Assume df is your data frame with a column called txt

# Match text until the beginning of the URL
tweet.regex <- regexpr("^.*(?=http)", df$txt, perl=T)

# Extract tweet text
tweet <- substr(df$txt, tweet.regex, attr(tweet.regex, "match.length"))

# Match text from the beginning of the URL to the next space
url.regex <- regexpr("http[^ ]+(?= )", df$txt, perl=T)

# Extract URL
url <- substr(df$txt, url.regex, url.regex + attr(url.regex, "match.length"))

# Match the date
date.regex <- regexpr("[A-Za-z]+ \\d+, \\d{4} *$", df$txt, perl=T)

# Extract date
date <- substr(df$txt, date.regex, date.regex + attr(date.regex, "match.length"))

# Combine results
tweet.df <- data.frame(tweet, url, date, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

For each one, we're using a regular expression to match a piece of the tweet, getting the indices of the beginning of the matches, then extracting using `substr()` from the match index to the sum of the match index and the match length.

The first regex, `^.*(?=http)` uses a lookahead to match from the beginning of the string, denoted `^`, to the last character before `http`.

The second, `http[^ ]+(?= )` matches from `http` to the next space since spaces can't be part of URLs.

Since dates are in a fixed format, we can use a more straightforward regex to get dates. `[A-Za-z]+` matches any letter "a" through "z" regardless of case. `\\d` gets a single digit, i.e. 0-9. Adding `+` means match the last thing at least one time. Then `\\d{4}` means match exactly 4 digits in a row. We can make sure we don't get a date that's included inside of a tweet by matching until the end of the string. Here we're using `*` (that's a space plus `*`) to get any trailing blanks, then we get the string end with `$`.

The `regexpr()` function returns a vector of the match indices. That is, it tells you what position in the string it found the beginning of the match in. The vector also has an attribute called `match.length` which tells you how long the match is. We extract that information using `attr(..., "match.length")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `stringr` package.

```
library("stringr")
dat <- c("Thank you, everyone!  indyref http://t.co/1kTzqjyGE7 Sep 18, 2014 ",
"As the polls close, total likes on the @YesScotland Facebook page have passed David Cameron s one.  indyref  voteYes http://t.co/x7IoB1EtfY Sep 18, 2014 ",
"We can be proud of  indyref, which has seen a flourishing of Scotland’s self-confidence as a nation  VoteYes http://t.co/1OqxvbpoS9 Sep 18, 2014 ",
"We can afford world-class public services. A Yes vote means we can strengthen our NHS.  VoteYes  indyref http://t.co/D9Vn5OqStV Sep 18, 2014 ",
"This is a once in a lifetime opportunity to choose a new and better path for Scotland  VoteYes  indyref http://t.co/9knT6Mx4vZ Sep 18, 2014 ",
"Our young people shouldn t have to leave to find decent jobs.  VoteYes  indyref http://t.co/vAE164f0Oy Sep 18, 2014 ")

dates <- str_extract(dat, "[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}")
url <- str_extract(dat, "http://t.co/[0-9A-Za-z]{10}")
text <- gsub("  indyref.+", "", dat)
df <- data.frame(dates, text, url, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Your regex to get dates will match dates that are part of the tweet text. I'd recommend adding `$` to the end to ensure you're only matching the date at the end of the string.